# How to add class to the currently clicked elemnt on the menu item

Tags: jquery

Once clicked on the menu item , i am trying to remove the class active of the previous one , and trying to add it to the current clicked elemnt .

But could you please let me know what i am doing wrong in this case

https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/1/

```
    $(document).on('click', '.res', function(event)
    {

     $('.menu .res').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

var activeslidenumber = $(this).index();    

alert(activeslidenumber);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

- In your anchor element, add a class called "menu-item"
- Handle the click event of "menu-item" and set the active class on it
- Also, add closing tag for the `</ul>` (it was missing in your fiddler code)

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/6/

**HTML**

```
     <div class="top-nav">
         <span class="menu"> <img src="images/icon.png" alt=""></span>
           <ul class="res">
              <li ><a class="menu-item active" href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Three</a></li>
           </ul>           
     </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-item', function(event)
{    
    $('.res .menu-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');  

});
```

And here is **another simple solution**: https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Write click for menu li's .res li.
2. Remove all active. `$(".res li a").removeClass('active');`
3. then add current active `$(this).addClass('active');`

   ```
       $(document).on('click', '.res li', function(event)
       {            

       $(".res li a").removeClass('active');
       $(this).find('a').addClass('active')    
       var activeslidenumber = $(this).index();        
       alert(activeslidenumber);    

       });
   ```

Comment: Thank you but why is it loosing active class on the clicked element .

Comment: On click just remove all active class in all element and add active class on clicked element.

Comment: If you go with @AndiAR's solution, here is the change you have to make: https://jsfiddle.net/x1f5n9qo/7/ (@AndiAR, please jump in and feel free to make any changes to this fiddle)